# Command doesn't register MinecraftForge 1.8

Tags: java, minecraft, minecraft-forge

I'm trying to register a command after a user executes the command, I have created a inner class that implements ICommand and I am sure it is valid. I have also checked to make sure the MinecraftServer instance I got was valid and not null. Here is what I did to register the command:

```
CommandHandler commandHandler = (CommandHandler) minecraftServer.getCommandManager();
commandHandler.registerCommand(new Command());
```

This doesn't work and when I try to execute the command, it shows that the command is unknown.

Answer (score 3):

Well, you need a command handler of course. Here is a barebones version of mine.
Check the code for comments for helpful hints.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import akka.actor.FSM.Event;
import net.minecraft.command.CommandException;
import net.minecraft.command.ICommand;
import net.minecraft.command.ICommandSender;
import net.minecraft.entity.Entity;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayer;
import net.minecraft.entity.player.EntityPlayerMP;
import net.minecraft.event.ClickEvent;
import net.minecraft.event.HoverEvent;
import net.minecraft.util.BlockPos;
import net.minecraft.util.ChatComponentText;
import net.minecraft.util.EnumChatFormatting;
import net.minecraft.world.World;
import net.minecraftforge.fml.common.FMLCommonHandler;


public class InspectCommand implements ICommand
{ 
    private final List aliases;

    public InspectCommand() 
    { 
        aliases = new ArrayList(); 
        // These are the commands that can be used to invoke your command
        aliases.add("whotookmycookies"); 

        aliases.add("wtmc");

        aliases.add("co");
    } 

    @Override 
    public int compareTo(Object o)
    { 
        return 0; 
    } 

    @Override 
    public String getName() 
    { 
        // The big name of your command
        return "whotookmycookies"; 
    } 

    @Override         
    public String getCommandUsage(ICommandSender var1) 
    {
        // Help file summary
        return "whotookmycookies <text>";
    }

    @Override 
    public boolean isUsernameIndex(String[] var1, int var2) 
    {
        // Can the user use this command I think
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public List getAliases() 
    {
        // Return all the aliases
        return this.aliases;
    }

    @Override
    public void execute(ICommandSender sender, String[] args) throws CommandException 
    {
        World world = sender.getEntityWorld();

        // Wanna execute on the player side? Do stuff here.
        if (world.isRemote)
        {
        }
        // Execute serverside
        else
        {
            if (args.length == 0)
            {
                // Send a message to the command giving entity. Remember, this can also be a command block and at this point you haven't done a type check yet.
                sender.addChatMessage(new ChatComponentText("WHO TOOK MY COOKIES! Seriously though. type an argument. type /wtmc help to see available commands"));
                return;
            } 

            if (sender instanceof EntityPlayer)
            {
            } 
        }
    }

    @Override
    public List addTabCompletionOptions(ICommandSender sender, String[] args, BlockPos pos)
    {
        // Look at native Minecraft commands like /tp to see how to return this if you wish to add tab auto completion.
        return null;
    }
}
```

Then you need to register that command during the `FMLServerStartingEvent`

```
@EventHandler
public void start(FMLServerStartingEvent event) 
{
    event.registerServerCommand(new InspectCommand());
}
```

Comment: Can you update your question with your command definition and registration?